# How to write a line only once in a text file

Tags: c#

I have two text files `bala.txt` and `bala1.txt`

`bala.txt` contains text line by line as

```
balamurugan,rajendran,chendurpandian
christopher
updateba
```

`bala1.txt` contains text line by line as

```
 ba
```

Here i need to check `bala1.txt` with `bala.txt` and write into a log file as

```
Pattern Name:ba
LineNo : 1 : balamurugan,rajendran,chendurpandian
LineNo : 3 : updateba
```

now its writing like this

```
 Pattern Name :ba
LineNo : 1 : balamurugan,rajendran,chendurpandian
LineNo : 2 : christopher
Pattern Name :ba
LineNo : 3 : updateba
```

Here is my code

```
while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
                                    {
              if (line.IndexOf(line2,StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) != -1)
                    dest.WriteLine("Pattern Name :" + line2);
                    dest.WriteLine("LineNo : " + counter.ToString() + " : " + line);
                                        counter++;
                                    }
                                    file.BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                                        //(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                                    counter = 1;
```

I dont know how to write pattern name ba only once...Any suggestion??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do the least amount of change to your code, you can change it like this:

```
        bool patternwritten = false;
        while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
                                {
          if (line.IndexOf(line2,StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) != -1)
                if( !patternwritten){
                  dest.WriteLine("Pattern Name :" + line2);
                  patternwritten = true;
                }
                dest.WriteLine("LineNo : " + counter.ToString() + " : " + line);
                                    counter++;
                                }
                                file.BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                                    //(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                                counter = 1;
```